# Counting orders Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have a simple application which sum amount of my orders and payments only per same day and submit them in table. I have a drawer which starting every day and when finish the day I can submit total sum of day (orders,pay in/out) and at the next day I'm starting from begining with 0 cash again. 
My question: Is that a possible to end my drawer and start it again in the same day with 0 cash multiple times per day?
Now if I start again I'm seeing all orders whose are already maked today.

My controller:

```
public function show($id)
    {
        $locations = Location::find($id)->orders()->whereDate('created_at', '=', Carbon::today()->toDateString()); //show orders
        $wallets = Location::find($id)->locsales()->whereDate('created_at', '=', Carbon::today()->toDateString()); //show payments
        $loc = Location::find($id); //to show location name

        return view('location')
        ->with('locations', $locations)
        ->with('wallets', $wallets)
        ->with('loc', $loc);
    }
```

Part of my view:

```
       <div class="card-body">

                        <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="list-group-item">
                        <label for="location">Location: {{$loc->location_id}}</label>

                        <form method="post" action="/post_drawer">
                        @csrf           
<input type="number" class="form-control" name="start_cash" id="start_cash" value="{{$wallets->sum('start_cash')}}" readonly>
                        <label for="info">Amount of orders(today):</label>
                        <input type="number" class="form-control" name="amount" id="amount" value="{{$locations->sum('total')}}" readonly>
```

Update 1: I added to orders table and to my view option to submit added_to_drawer field with boolean and now my controller is like that:

```
$locations = Location::find($id)->orders()->whereDate('created_at', '=', Carbon::today()->toDateString())->whereNull('added_to_drawer');
```

May be I'm doing something wrong but it doesn't work.

Update 2:I maked my controller to show only records with value 1 and now it's working correct.

```
$locations = Location::find($id)->orders()
        ->where('added_to_drawer', 1)


$affected = DB::table('orders')->whereid('location', $id)->update(array('added_to_drawer' => 0));
        $affected = DB::table('wallets')->where('location_id', $id)->update(array('added_to_drawer' => 0));
```

But I have another problem. When I close my drawer he update(reset) all locations
drawer to 0.
For example - I want to update only this locations where name is New York but to be dynamically. Not like that: `where('location','=','New York')`
I tried it like this: `where('location','=' $id)` but it's doesn't work.

Comment: you can try with one more field in orders table like `added_to_drawer` with boolean when you want to start new drawer make all to true and in query you can write `->whereNull('added_to_drawer')`

Comment: update your question with what you have done and whats the error?